# Using iframe to successfully login to another website

Tags: html, authentication, iframe

I've been developing HTML and the main component is displaying a workable website. The website requires the user to login. However, I've tried many times to login, it wouldn't move to the next webpage. I know the username and password. If I open the real website using my browser it will let me through the next page, basically doing what's it supposed to do.

I've tried the codes below from previous answers, but still wouldn't work.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post"
     action="https://simrs.simkes.id/login">
  <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="login"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="Password" value="pass"/>
</form>

<div data-jiis="cc" id="doc-info"></div>
<div class="container">
  <iframe id="frame" name="frame"></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
  document.getElementById('login').submit();

  // once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
  var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
  iframe.onload = function() {
      if (iframe.src != "https://simrs.simkes.id/dashboard/") {
          iframe.src = "https://simrs.simkes.id/dashboard/";
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: did you test the login procedure in the browser, without this html? Test with F12 web tools?

Comment: just checked it, it shows: 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://simrs.simkes.id/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

any clues to fix this?

Comment: include the stylesheet with either https:// or just //

Comment: by the way, why not replace the line with Lihat Password with an eye icon right-side  of password input? And remove the top instruction, because everybody understands a login page?

Comment: how do you do that? Sorry, I'm new to all of this

Comment: did you fix the mixed content issue?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Actually I wasn't the one who developed the website, my client did. I'm going to do a usability testing for this website, which you've kinda did just now :)

Comment: I'm having trouble in fixing the mixed content issue. My question was, how do you include https:// or // into stylesheet? Where am I suppose to do that?

Comment: e.g.: `<link rel="stylesheet"    href="//fonts.googleapis.com/xxx.css" />` between <head> and </head>

Comment: still. It won't work

Comment: Hey. After I double check it's not the iframe fault, but the original website. The https problem appears on the original website.

Comment: Turns out the problem is in Chrome. Due to its same-site cookies policy, I couldn't log in to the web that I wanted to go.